# Couchbase - Autonomous Operator: Chown: changing ownership of ‘var/lib/couchbase/inbox’: Read-only file system

Tags: kubernetes, couchbase

I have set up my CB cluster following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMIX4Aob_8Q&ab_channel=Couchbase. Everything is working well (seemingly), the DNS records are being updated correctly, but all the Couchbase pods are stuck at this:

```
Starting Couchbase Server -- Web UI available at http://<ip>:8091
and logs available in /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs
chown: changing ownership of 'var/lib/couchbase/inbox/..data': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of 'var/lib/couchbase/inbox/pkey.key': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of 'var/lib/couchbase/inbox/chain.pem': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of 'var/lib/couchbase/inbox/..2021_04_18_18_23_11.298228169/pkey.key': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of 'var/lib/couchbase/inbox/..2021_04_18_18_23_11.298228169/chain.pem': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of 'var/lib/couchbase/inbox/..2021_04_18_18_23_11.298228169': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of 'var/lib/couchbase/inbox': Read-only file system
```

They are not turning to "green" on the Kubernetes console, and trying to connect to them gives me a `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error.

I was able to `port-forward` into the console, but all the nodes are red and no buckets were created.

Comment: Hi, Would you mind providing some yaml config files enough to reproduce the issues? Where are you running this? What kubernetes version?

Comment: Sadly this frustrated me so much that I moved in a different direction that rendered this moot.